# Different width divs in the same row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put 3 `div`s(with different `width`s respectively : 10%,70% & 20%) in the same row but the middle one always go full width of the page.

Here is my code:

```css
  #left-bar {
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #FF0000;
  }
  #middle-bar {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #6600FF;
  }
  #right-bar {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #99FF99;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="left-bar"></div>
  <div id="middle-bar"></div>
  <div id="right-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you welcome, btw you commented on your question instead my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `div` is a block level element that's why they aren't in the same row.

You have a few options to fix this:

#### option with CSS flexbox:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%
}

.row>div {
  /*demo purposes */
  height: 30px;
}

#left-bar {
  flex: 0 10%;
  background-color: #F00;
}

#middle-bar {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #60F;
}

#right-bar {
  flex: 0 20%;
  background-color: #9F9;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="left-bar"></div>
  <div id="middle-bar"></div>
  <div id="right-bar"></div>
</div>
```

---

(old options)

#### option with `display:inline-block`

```css
.row {
  /*fix inline-block gap*/
  font-size: 0;
}

.row>div {
  display: inline-block;
  /*demo purposes */
  height: 30px;
}

#left-bar {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #F00;
}

#middle-bar {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #60F;
}

#right-bar {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #9F9;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="left-bar"></div>
  <div id="middle-bar"></div>
  <div id="right-bar"></div>
</div>
```

#### option with `display:table-[cell]`

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
}

.row>div {
  display: table-cell;
  /*demo purposes */
  height: 30px;
}

#left-bar {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #F00;
}

#middle-bar {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #60F;
}

#right-bar {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #9F9;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="left-bar"></div>
  <div id="middle-bar"></div>
  <div id="right-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The table-cell option actually doesn't work in some internet explorer versions. But the same result can be achieved with the property float:

```css
#left-bar{
          width:10%;
          background-color: #FF0000;
 }
 #middle-bar{
          width:70%;
          background-color: #6600FF;
 }
 #right-bar{
          width:20%;
          background-color: #99FF99;
 }

.row > div {float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="left-bar">a</div>
  <div id="middle-bar">b</div>
  <div id="right-bar">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You copied me :)... kind of, but either way. Ours are better practice than the table solution ;)

Comment: I wrote this: *The table-cell option actually doesn't work in some internet explorer versions* because the first answer was suggesting that option, but then the guy changed his answer and converted it in a super answer. I forgot that people here do that.

Comment: you are wrong here "*The table-cell option actually doesn't work in some internet explorer versions.*" See more info about `display:table`  on [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

Comment: I'm applying styles to page since 2004. I can assure you by experience that the displat table-cell isn't universal (now it is).

Comment: And FYI @AdamBuchananSmith I don't copy answers. I get here an answer some question when the flow is slow at work. I'm not interested in reputation and stuff like that.

Comment: We are talking about the present and as you see on the link i mention it works in IE8+ and every other current browser ;)

Comment: I think we all agree on this lol... Write your comments below the "table" answer :/

Comment: We are not talking about the present. You are talking about the present.

Comment: @DaseinA I was not saying you were, just messing with you bro. I also, agreed with your answer as it was cleaner than mine. I agree with your answer 100% (just added some sarcasm) - sorry

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith No hurts feeling. But the users copying other's answers is something I've noticed here and it actually happened to me. A user provided a wrong answer. I posted mine. And he changed his completely with my approach and better "look". He got the best answer. It seems like people here are more interested in getting points than in to help and to learn.

Comment: @DaseinA I marked yours up out of good faith :) Ours are very close, but you took a very different approach with less code. I really don't care either about these stupid point thingies, they don't buy me nothing. I just like trying to help when I can.

Comment: @DaseinA I'm hoping you're not referring to me at all, because I did mine in first place then after I posted i realized one second option/solution I could've added and I was editing my question while you post (therefore I don't even knew that were a new answer, since I was editing mine). And To be cleared my answer only talks about `display`s while both of yours talks about `float`ing. so very different.

Comment: @dippas If you mean the experience I had with that user that stole my answer, that was in another question like a month ago

Comment: @DaseinA ya was talking about that :) that's really bad, and yes you are right allot of users here only care about rep instead helping/learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
#left-bar{
          width:10%;
          background-color: #FF0000;
          float:left;
 }
 #middle-bar{
          width:70%;
          background-color: #6600FF;
          float:left;
 }
 #right-bar{
          width:20%;
          background-color: #99FF99;
          float:left;
 }
```

If that doesn't work, please provide more html and css because the problem will be somewhere else. Also, verify that you have heights set for your divs.